# .htaccess issue under WAMP server

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to change some of the url names using htaccess.

ex;
mg_com_tr/index.php to mg_com_tr/home

I tried many different code samples inside my htaccess file, but nothing seems to work.

I never worked with the htaccess file before,so in order to test it, I found some example codes just for removing the ".php" extension.

When I try this code, I'm not getting any errors, but its not removing the .php extension either.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The only working code I found is this one;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This removes the .php extension, however whatever I try I couldn't manage to change

```
http://localhost/mg_com_tr/index.php
```

into

```
http://localhost/mg_com_tr/home
```

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the path

Both the index.php and htaccess file is located at
D:\wamp\www\mg_com_tr\

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^home  index.php    [NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule  ^home  /index.php    [NC,L]
```

Comment: still not working. it seems like my htaccess file is not functioning cproperly. I tried more than 20 different code samples and the only one actually do something is the one I posted.

Comment: htaccess can really be a pain in the arsenal :) did you change any settings for apache ? or maybe you need to add `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` at the beginning and end of your .htaccess file.

Comment: I changed AllowOverride all and enabled the LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so. I tried almost every combination, but still no result. The htaccess file itself is working, but for some weird reason rewrite is not working